# session in java application

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, session

I wanted add session into my project and when the user logout as needed I made session attribute null in the logout javascript function which is in on the top of jsp file. But once I login to the system and refresh the page the session make itself null. Here is my function.

```
function logoutFunction() {
            var txt;
            if (confirm("Need to Logout!") == true) {
        <% session.setAttribute("Name",null); %>
                document.location.href = 'Logout_Con';
                location = 'index.jsp';
            } else {
                location = 'welcome_page.jsp';
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
        }
```

is this wrong?:(

Comment: how do you declare your session variable?

Comment: JavaScript on a JSP does _not_ affect the server side so you'll provide the server side session management.

Comment: This line `<% session.setAttribute("Name",null); %>` is executed before the web page is loaded on the client side. So the javascript will not see that line at all. See how `JSP` works, you can see about `PHP` that works the same.

Comment: HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("Name", username);

Answer (score 2):

You can't add Java code inside Javascript. Java code is executed before.

You need to submit parameter of logout as input name logout with value as Y and then check it,as:

```
<% 
boolean logoutSubmitted = "Y".equals(request.getParameter("logout"));
if (logoutSubmitted == true) {
   session.setAttribute("Name",null); 
}
%>
```

Comment: Thank you very much from answering my question. it works. :)